# What is the difference between batch_size from fit() method and batch from LSTM inputs ? Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I can't understand the difference between the batch_size of the `fit()` method and the batch coming from a dimension of the LSTM inputs : A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
(see inputs keras : https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/).

To this I can also add `epochs`.

If I have a dataset of 1000 values whose format is already refactored for LSTM and I have a timestep of 50 (so 50 LSTM cells), how will the data behave? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The input dimension of the *layer* will be `(batch_size, ...)` because `model.fit()` will split your input in chunks of `(batch_size, ...)`, no matter how many samples you have. This is done along the first dimension, so the time step dimension doesn't change anything.

Your input of shape...

```
(1000, 50, 25) # let's say you have 25 features
```

... will enter the LSTM layer like this:

```
(16, 50, 25) # let's say you have batch_size of 16
(16, 50, 25)
(16, 50, 25)
(16, 50, 25)
(16, 50, 25)
...
(1000 % 16, 50, 25)
```